# compile error with boost include when I using Rcpp in R

Tags: r, boost, rcpp

I got an error as below although I already have RTools and package BH.
(I'm using Win10 64-bit and R 3.5.1)

Rtools works well when I compile other packages.

I already saw many related q&a, but couldn't solve this.

Please help this newbie.

```
> sourceCpp('D:/Data/Drive/RCodes/scRNA-seq/TransSyn/TransSyn.cpp')
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" - 
DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/CEO/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" - 
I"D:/Data/Drive/RCodes/scRNA-seq/TransSyn"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c 
TransSyn.cpp -o TransSyn.o
TransSyn.cpp:5:37: fatal error: boost/functional/hash.hpp: No such file or 
directory
 #include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: TransSyn.o] Error 1
Error in sourceCpp("D:/Data/Drive/RCodes/scRNA-seq/TransSyn/TransSyn.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. 
Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

Comment: Have you linked to {BH}?
Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

From the compilation command we can learn that you are not including the `boost` headers from the `BH` package:

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include"
 -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/CEO/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" 
 -I"D:/Data/Drive/RCodes/scRNA-seq/TransSyn"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c
 TransSyn.cpp -o TransSyn.o
```

A `-I"C:/Users/CEO/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/BH/include"` is missing. You can fix this by adding

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
```

to `D:/Data/Drive/RCodes/scRNA-seq/TransSyn/TransSyn.cpp`. Of course, you have to make sure that `BH` is installed.